# How to pass command-line arguments in debug mode in VSCode with golang

Tags: debugging, go, command-line, visual-studio-code, arguments

I am having difficulty in passing command-line arguments in VSCode (debug mode) with golang.

Below is the small code example and the launch.json:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    flag1Ptr := flag.Bool("flag1", false, "flag1 is a flag")
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println(*flag1Ptr)
    fmt.Println("Hello, world")
}
```

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {},
            "args": [
                "-flag1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

> The output is always "false" for *flag1Ptr but it should be "true".
>
> Update: The issue disappeared after closing down VSCode and reopening it (I am on a Mac(osX))

Comment: I tested your code and it works for me. I get the value true with vscode debugger.

Comment: Very strange.  I am using a Mac (osX).  I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: I’ve tested it on a linux computer. I don’t have a mac around to test it.

Comment: I just added "trace": "log" to the launch file and it does not output anything new.  I suspect my setup is not running the launch.json file

Comment: I am not sure what happened (I did close down VSCode and reopened it) but it started working.  The trace:log file also started working.

Comment: I experienced similar things too. It looks like restarting vscode when we see something unexpected is the first thing to do. Good to see you solved your problem.

Comment: I got the same issue. Like the args are ignored

Answer (score 44):

list all params, for example,
command is:

```
"hello.exe -in InfoEntity.java -out aa.out"
```

the debug config is:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {},
            "args": ["-in", "InfoEntity.java", "-out", "aa.out"]
        }
    ]
}
```