# vs code debuging go tests not passing flags

Tags: go, debugging, testing, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I`m trying to config a debugger on vs-code to some tests in go. I have to pass some flags to it, but it's not working well.

main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func DoTheThing() {
    flag1Ptr := flag.Bool("flag1", false, "flag1 is a flag")
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println(*flag1Ptr)
    fmt.Println("Hello, world")
}

func main() {
    DoTheThing()
}
```

main_test.go

```golang
package main

import "testing"

func TestDoTheThing(t *testing.T) {
    DoTheThing()
}
```

launch.json

```json
{
    "name": "Launch app",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    "mode": "auto",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "args": [
        "-flag1"
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Run Tests",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    "mode": "test",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "args": [
        "--", "-flag1"
    ]
}
```

if I run it with Launch app config it pass the value in the right way, but using the test one it do not set the parameter

output using Launch app config

```
true
Hello, world
```

output using Run Tests config

```
false
Hello, world
```

Comment: what is the error message and what flags are not passing as you hoped?
`go.testTags` is not a valid launch.json property, `buildFlags` arepassed to dlv's `--build-flags` so not a place to pass application flags. 
And also try `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/integration_tests/service1"`

Comment: i do not receive an error message. The problem is just that the flag is passed as empty.

Comment: The argument i need is -server-address=localhost

Comment: @Hana I did some improvements on the question with better examples

Comment: I am aware I am not answering your question, but wouldn't it be better to move the parsing of the flags into the `main` function and have the tests passing the values in a clear way to the `DoTheThing` function? If you do like this, you may have different tests for different cases. Otherwise you are forced to have different **launch** configurations for different tests.

Comment: @pici Here I'm a simpler example than my real project. In the real project, it makes more sense to pass some info as parameters when running the tests because we have a lot of suites and configs to set for different environments. To run the tests we use makefiles to organize this, but i'm trying to config a debugger now ;)

Comment: If your `main` launches a server, e.g. a web server, and you want to be able to set breakpoints and stop the execution at these breakpoints when a request comes in, then you should be able to do this with the `launch` configuration you already have working. If you want to debug just the `DoTheThing` function, then I suggest you to create a test `DoTheThing_test` and pass the flags from the test. Which means, as I wrote above, to move the parsing of the flags out of `DoTheThing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

var flag1Ptr *bool

func init(){
    flag1Ptr = flag.Bool("flag1", false, "flag1 is a flag")
}

func DoTheThing() {
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println(*flag1Ptr)
    fmt.Println("Hello, world")
}

func main() {
    DoTheThing()
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "name": "Launch app",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    "mode": "auto",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "args": [
        "-flag1"
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Run Tests",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    "mode": "test",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "args": ["-flag1"]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So when I define the flags in the init() it'll be accepted as flags to the debug?

Comment: This worked pretty well, but not i'm not able to use -test flgas, such as -test.v. When i try i receive "Flag provided but not defined: -test.v"

Comment: i fixed it adding testing.Init() on my package init :)