# How to debug cobra command test with VS Code?

Tags: go, vscode-debugger, go-cobra

I have a go program using cobra commands. I can run and debug a command with

```
{
    "name": "Reporting1",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    "mode": "auto",
    "program": "main.go",
    "args":["Reporting1"],
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
},
```

This will start Reporting1 in debug mode.   I have a Reporting_test.go

```
//go:build unit
// +build unit

package cmd

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestReportingCmd(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()
...
```

When executing "`go test ./cmd/... --short -v -json -tags=unit`" It runs all the tests, also the ones from the other commands but I am unable to do it in debugger mode. Is there any launch configuration which will allow me to debug it with VS Code?
Thanks
Eckard.

I have tried any kind of arguments in lauch.json for "program": "main.go" and "args" but did not got it running.

"program": "Reporting_test.go"
did not work because inside I call the reporting function which is defined via Reproting_generated.go where the reportingCmd is called which is implemented in executeReporting.go
It would be OK to just run one test or all the tests at once in debug mode.

Comment: You may try to replace ```args``` parameter in launch.json with following: ```"args": ["-test.v", "--", "Reporting1"]```

Comment: Unfortunatley that did not work for me it is just doing "Executing Main Run command" but neither command itself nor tests are executed

Comment: How exactly do you try to run the tests? I suggest that you switch to ```Reporting_test.go``` , press ```Ctrl+F5``` (Run without debugging) or ```F5``` (Start debugging). You can have two configurations in ```launch.json``` - one for running tests and one for running ```main```.

Comment: You can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71767280/debugging-go-tests-with-command-line-arguments-in-vscode) for more details.

Comment: As written above I run "go test ./cmd/... --short -v -json -tags=unit"  in console/bash. But I am not able to start this command via launch configuration From the mentioned thread I have a "run package tests" and "run test files" but no debug test, neither of the run tests works.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got an answer from a colleague: adding:

```
"go.testFlags": [
    "-tags=unit,integration",
    "-short",
    "-v"
]
```

to settings.json resolved the issue. No I can run in debug mode.